# Vim: Using rails.vim, how do I make rails.vm use rspec instead of testunit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I'm using rails.vim and when I use :A on a model file, it opens the corresponding testunit file. How do I make it open the corresponding rspec file?

Comment: Do you have both a test/unit and a spec for the same class/file?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I have both an rspec and test/unit file for the model I was trying.

Comment: Looks like if I remove my test/unit file, then :A will open the corresponding rspec file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails.vim will load test/unit first (if it exists), then rspec.

So, fix the framework you use most often and keep your stuff in either the test or spec folders.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I found out. I removed my testunit stuff; now when I use :A it loads my corresponding rspec files, just like I wanted.

Comment: How exactly does it "load" it? It keeps trying to open test/unit/whatever_test.rb for me, even though I use RSpec and only have the spec/ directory (test/ does not exist.)